# How to convert links to lowercase using XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt

In my XML workflow I've set it up to build hyperlinks to specific terms which we are linking to definitions in our app. I want to convert the link attribute to lowercase to standardize naming conventions.

The XSLT already creates the link by concatenating multiple words with "_" underscores. But how can I also convert the uppercase words to lowercase at the same time?

I've set up a variable for converting the words but how do I add this to the existing template?

Here is some sample XML:

```
<APPENDIX>
    <Subsection>
        <DL>
            <DT>Committee</DT> 
            <DD>The <em>Committee</em> is the appropriate <em>Committee</em> of the <em>Governing Body</em></DD>
            <DT>Golf Skill or Reputation</DT> 
            <DD><text>It is a matter for the <em>Governing Body</em> to decide whether a particular <em>amateur golfer</em> has <em>golf skill or reputation</em>. </text></DD>
            <DT>Governing Body</DT>  
            <DD><text>The <em>Governing Body</em> for the administration of the Rules of Amateur Status in any country is the national golf union or association of that country.  </text></DD>
        </DL>
    </Subsection>
</APPENDIX>
```

Here is the XSLT that converts the text to a link:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:variable name="smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
        <xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="''" />

        <xsl:apply-templates select="APPENDIX"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="em">
        <a href="{concat('#',translate(normalize-space(.), ' ', '_'))}">
            <em><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/></em>
        </a>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've left off the templates that convert the `DL`, `DT` and `DD` elements. If you don't need them I'll keep it simple. Basically, those elements are just brought back as is.

I just need to covert the links like `href="Governing_Body"` to lowercase like: `href="governing_body"`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare your variables in the top-level if you wish them to be seen by your `em` template. After that, all you have to do is to call your existing `concat()` inside another `translate`, to convert the cases:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
    <xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="APPENDIX"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="em">
        <a href="{translate(concat('#',translate(normalize-space(.), ' ', '_')), $uppercase, $smallcase)}">
            <em><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/></em>
        </a>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks! I just couldn't figure out how to concat and translate and translate in one template.

Answer (score 2):

XSLT 2.0 has [fn:upper-case()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-upper-case) and [fn:lower-case()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-lower-case) functions.

However in case you are using of XSLT 1.0, you can use [translate()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-translate):

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
    <xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(doc, $smallcase, $uppercase)" />
</xsl:template>
```